# how to select the tab in excel programmatically with c#

Tags: c#, excel, com

When I open a workbook in excel it goes to the last tab and scroll position I had open.
I want to write some c# code to open excel workbook and select the first tab, and scroll to cell A1, so when it opens it will be on that that worksheet. all solutions I tried so far produced exceptions:

```
worksheet.Select(Type.Missing)
(worksheet as Excel._Worksheet).Activate();
excelApp.Goto(worksheet.get_range("A1", Type.Missing), true);
```

Comment: What exceptions did these attempts produce?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet firstSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
firstSheet.Select(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
excelApp.get_Range("$A1", hmissing).Select();
```